# New User New Ubuntu Install 22.04: Trouble with gsettings change persisting past reboot

Tags: gsettings, dash-to-dock

I am recently starting over to Linux from Windows and am just trying out Ubuntu 22.04 now. So far I have not made any major changes to the system other than installing a few snap applications. One thing I want to do is to minimize windows when I click them.

I found the command to allow me to minimize windows which is:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize'
```

When I reboot my system, the changes are reverted and I have to type this command each time. Now from what I see online, the command should persist and I'm having trouble finding anyone else having this problem where it is not.

Any advise for how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: This can occur if folks take a shortcut installing Ubuntu by copying instead of installing. Did you follow EVERY step of the install tutorial? Did you make a proper LiveUSB, then boot that USB?

Comment: This can occur if folks save a desktop session and then keep rebooting into that saved session. Did you enter any unusual commands that include the word `session`?

Comment: This can occur of folks install an overlayfs. Did you install the `overlayroot` package?

Comment: Thanks for telling me about those things to check.

I followed the standard install as far as I can tell. I'll give this a try again just to see. But I downloaded the image, used Rufus to make a bootable USB then selected to install and stuck with most of the defaults except opting for LVM and third party drivers.

I did not use any commands such as session or overlayroot and had not done anything much with the terminal other than gsettings.

Comment: I'll update this post again once I try re-installing just to make sure I didn't do anything there.